# Elasticsearch Fails to query exactly for an array Field inside the Document

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, nest

I have the  following data in elasticsearch type called 'bank'

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "name": "ICIC",
        "balance": "$2,574.27",
        "friends": [
            {
                "roleid": 0,
                "name": "Alana Shepard",
                "isactive": true
            },
            {
                "roleid": 1,
                "name": "Katheryn Hatfield",
                "isactive": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "name": "SBK",
        "balance": "$2,346.44",
        "friends": [
            {
                "roleid": 0,
                "name": "Hinton Kaufman",
                "isactive": true
            },
            {
                "roleid": 1,
                "name": "Miles Alford",
                "isactive": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I try to fetch the document where **friends.roleid = 1 and friends.isactive=true** .  The DSL query requested is as follows,

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "friends.roleid": {
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "friends.isactive": {
                            "value": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The Results expected is the object with **_id = 2** .  But The actual result came was both _id =1 and _id = 2 . It will be greatly appreciated if anyone helps to find what is the problem in the DSL query .  Thank you

Comment: You need to declare your `friends` field as `nested` type. See why here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/nested-objects.html

Comment: Val How to write a nested query and a normal dsl query in the same request?

Comment: You can use `bool/must` to combine them together the same way you did to combine the `term` queries inside the nested one.

Comment: @Val Should I need  to write another query object in addition to the nested query. Because When I specify a term query for 'name'  using bool/must inside the same nested query , the search fails to fetch any data

Comment: Maybe, update your answer with your actual query and I'll comment there

Comment: Having collection inside Elastic search type will cause the issue you are facing. Your document should be as flat as possible. If you have a situation in which you may have objects on which you can have filters then you must use [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) nested mapping.This enforces one to flatten the collection inside the document.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed be making the Field "friends" as a nested object . And the DSL query is  reconstructed as  follows  ,

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "friends",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "friends.roleid": {
                                    "value": 1
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "friends.isactive": {
                                    "value": "true"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The  path  in the DSL query specifies the nested object . The  elasticsearch documentation  reference   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html   would help a lot.